# Problema de estructura c++

Tags: c++

Mi problema es el siguiente. Elabore un código en el cual, de acuerdo a las estructuras y vectores de personas, muestre el nombre de las personas que están discapacitadas o no. Todo corre bien, pero el out muestra solo una (1) persona en las discapacitadas, por mas que ingrese. Desde ya muchas gracias si ven mi error.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


struct personas 
{
    string nombre;

}persona[10] = {};

int main()
{
    int cant = 0, duda;
    string invalida[10] = {};
    string noInvalida[10] = {};
    string discapacidad;
    int cantI = 0, cantNoI = 0;

    cout << "\nIngrese cantidad de personas: " << endl;
    cin >> cant;

    for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese nombre: " << endl;
        cin >> persona[i].nombre;
        cout << "Seleccione una opcion: 1.Posee discapacidad 2.No posee discapacidad" << endl;
        cin >> duda;

        if (duda == 1)
        {
            while (cantI < cant)
            {
                invalida[i] = (persona[i].nombre);
                cantI++;
            }
        }
        else if(duda == 2)
        {
            while (cantNoI < cant)
            {
                noInvalida[i] = (persona[i].nombre);
                cantNoI++;
            }
        }
    }


    cout << "\nPersonas con discapacidad: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
    {
        cout << invalida[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nPersonas sin discapacidad: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
    {
        cout << noInvalida[i] << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te estas complicando sin razón con ese problema. Esos `while` son totalmente innecesarios y estás desaprovechando la potencia de los structs para indexar cada elemento.

Yo propongo que el struct lo cambies así:

```
struct personas {
    string nombre;
    int discap;
}persona[10];
```

Y luego en el código principal se carga la estructura con *nombre - discapacidad* y finalmente se recorre la estructura buscando los elementos correspondientes.

```
int cant=0, cont=0;

cout << "\nIngrese cantidad de personas: " ;
cin >> cant;

// Cargar estructura con datos
for(int i=0; i<cant; i++) {
    cout << "Ingrese nombre: ";
    cin >> persona[i].nombre;
    cout << "Seleccione una opcion: 1.Posee discapacidad 2.No posee discapacidad" << endl;
    cin >> persona[i].discap;
}

// Recorrer la estructura en búsqueda de valores
cout << "\nPersonas con discapacidad: " << endl;
for(int i=0; i<cant; i++) {
    if(persona[i].discap == 1) {
        cout << persona[i].nombre << endl;
        cont++;
    }
}
cout << "Total: " << cont;
```

Solo te falta la parte de los que no están discapacitados, que es básicamente reescribir el `for`, o bien poner esa parte de código en una función.

Comment: Muchisimo mas preciso !, gracias amigo, funciona!

Answer (score 2):

revisé el código y hay varios detalles que debes cambiar:

1. El bloque del `if-else`

```cpp
if (duda == 1)
{
    invalida[cantI] = (persona[i].nombre);
    cantI++;
}
else if(duda == 2)
{
    noInvalida[cantNoI] = (persona[i].nombre);
    cantNoI++;
}
```

2. La condición de comparación el los ciclos `for`

```cpp
cout << "\nPersonas con discapacidad: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < cantI; i++)
{
    cout << invalida[i] << endl;
}

cout << "\nPersonas sin discapacidad: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < cantNoI; i++)
{
    cout << noInvalida[i] << endl;
}
```

Esta es la salida de la ejecución para 4 personas:

```sh
Ingrese cantidad de personas: 
4    
Ingrese nombre: 
Pedro
Seleccione una opcion: 1.Posee discapacidad 2.No posee discapacidad
1
Ingrese nombre: 
Jesus
Seleccione una opcion: 1.Posee discapacidad 2.No posee discapacidad
2
Ingrese nombre: 
Alberto
Seleccione una opcion: 1.Posee discapacidad 2.No posee discapacidad
1
Ingrese nombre: 
Juan
Seleccione una opcion: 1.Posee discapacidad 2.No posee discapacidad
2

Personas con discapacidad: 
Pedro
Alberto

Personas sin discapacidad: 
Jesus
Juan
```

Espero que resuelvas

Comment: que crack!, gracias man, alli corregi y funciono al toque